# Cannot find module 'bcryptjs'

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm-install, npm-package, bcryptjs

I installed @types/bcryptjs package in nodejs. When I import it only, there is no problem but when I use it in my code, like that:

console.log(bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password))

it gives me an error; Cannot find module 'bcryptjs'

What do I do?

I tried `npm rebuild`
I uninstalled this package and reinstalled it
But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed only `@types/bcryptjs`, you also need to install the library itself:

```
npm install bcryptjs
```